# Cakephp 2.x PHP Long running loop with computation

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

```
$savings_account = $this->Saving->query($this->Saving->getAllInterestExport($conditions));

if(!empty($savings_account)){
    foreach ($savings_account as $key => $save) {

    // COMPUTATION OF INTEREST HERE

    } 
}
```

Can someone help me give me suggestion how can i run a long running php loop ?

I am getting 504 gateway error . I need to loop my almost 10k records . and my php stops ing 1k. I am using PHP 7.3.27

Comment: It might depend on what's in the computation. Is it something that could potentially be done by SQL instead of PHP? Assuming not, then it's unlikely you'll get it down by a factor of 10. The typical methods then are to either do it in smaller batches, redirecting to a page with query parameters to tell it where to continue from, or else (usually a better solution, but can be more difficult to implement) build it as a process that runs from the command line (e.g. a cron job) where timeouts aren't an issue.

Comment: This is sort of to vague/broad to answer? Greg's ideas are all good. Pre-caching the result might also work- run a cronjob to update the computational cache in the background, or maybe calculate it on individual save instead of on a big batch query, etc. etc... Then just serve the cached values here, or only check here if the cache entry is stale, re-computing the few(er) that are stale as needed instead of the whole batch in real-time.